# Employee Assistance Program website software

Tags: wordpress

I've been asked to build an additional section onto a WordPress website to function as an [Employee Assistance Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employee_assistance_program) portal.

This portal is so that our company's EAP clients can provide a login to their own employees, so that they can access the EAP services our company provides.

I'm thinking there might be some EAP software I can install on a subdomain.

Do you know of any?

Else, the requirements for the EAP portal would be quite simple at this stage:

- Provide a login to EAP client companies that they can pass onto their staff.
- Once logged in, the staff member seeking assistance can choose from 8 sections such as grief and loss, depression, couples and relationship issues et al.
- These sections initially will be some reading that the EAP seeker can read.

I guess these requirements would ideally be published in a separate MU WordPress site on a subdomain, but I am unsure of what software can do it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to complete your entire EAP project only using what you have with additional pluggins as there are many that would meet your needs,  but before you jump to the final solution try to think long-term. Your question did not mention to many specifics about the requirements, but if all your looking for are personalized views, via a client's login, that would include information about the current EAP benefits? Well, that still just plain old WordPress with a membership pluggin that forwards the client to a specified page. Where the templates and DB will do the rest.

But I have the feeling that maybe you will need more than that later. To save yourself the most time and effort push your team to commit to thier needs and requirements and stick to it.  Otherwise next year you may have to scrap all the work your about to do and do something else.